# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show clicking a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<li><%= link_to('More Commented', posts_morecommented_path) %></li>
```

Error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show

Couldn't find Post with id=morecommented

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"morecommented"}
```

Where am I doing the mistake?

postscontroller#show action

```
def show      @post = Post.find(params[:id])      ...         end
```

morecommented.html.erb

```
<% @moreCommented.each do |t| %>
    <%= link_to t.title, :controller => '/posts', :action => 'show', :id => t.id %><br/>
<% end %>
```

rake routes

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
....      
posts_morecommented        /posts/morecommented(.:format) {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"morecommented"}
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :posts
  match "posts/:id/categ" => "posts#categ"
  match "posts/:id/tag_posts" => "posts#tag_posts"
  match "posts/searcharchive" => "posts#searcharchive"
  match "posts/morecommented" => "posts#morecommented"
```

Comment: add your `PostsController#show` action code and `routes.rb` or `rake routes` output

Comment: @MarkW, Why would i migrate the db now? What do you mean ?

Comment: @Bohdan, I have updated the original post/question.

Comment: move the `match "posts/morecommented" => "posts#morecommented"` before the call `resources :posts` in your routes.rb file

Comment: @Gerry, See original post again.

Comment: I show it. Did you try to move it before the call to resources :posts and not after? I mean 
`match "posts/morecommented" => "posts#morecommented"`
`resources :posts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move the match before the resources call

```
match "posts/morecommented" => "posts#morecommented"
resources :posts
```

Alternatively you can do

```
resources :posts do
   get :morecommented, on: :collection
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is inside your `routes.rb` file since routes are matched from the top to the bottom action `posts/morecommented` matches `posts/:id` action with `params[:id]` equal to `morecommented` One solution as Gerry mentioned is to change order and move the `match "posts/morecommented" => "posts#morecommented"` before the call `resources :posts` in your `routes.rb` file the other one is to set requirements on `:id` in your `posts/:id` route.