# Rails 4: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, nested-resources

This is a basic error and lots of people have ask similar questions, such as:

- [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524779/activerecordrecordnotfound-in-postscontrollershow)
- [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show clicking a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506969/activerecordrecordnotfound-in-postscontrollershow-clicking-a-link)

However, none of them actually helped me solve the issue I am facing now.

In my Rails 4 app, I have four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users, :path => 'account'

  resources :calendars do
    resources :posts, shallow: true
  end

end
```

Here is the problem: when I am on a calendar, for instance `http://localhost:3000/calendars/11`, I have all the posts that belong to this calendar displayed, with `Show`, `Edit` and `Destroy` links alongside each post.

When I click the `Edit` link, I am taken to `http://localhost:3000/posts/11/edit.5`* and I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#edit
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=11

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

*Note: I don't know why I keep getting this weird url, with `.5` at the end.*

Here is the content of my `PostsController`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    @post = @calendar.posts.create(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :subject, :format, :copy, :media)
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**: as per @Nathan's comment, here is the `edit.html.erb` view:

```
<h1>Editing Post</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

and here is the `_form.html.erb` partial used in it:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <p>
      <%= f.label :date %><br>
      <%= f.date_select :date %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :time %><br>
      <%= f.time_select :time %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :subject %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :format %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :format %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :copy %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :copy %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :media %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :media %>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE 2**: as per @danielricecodes' answer, here is the result of running `rake routes` in Terminal:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /account/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /account/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /account/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /account/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /account/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /account/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /account/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /account/confirmation(.:format)             devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /account/confirmation/new(.:format)         devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /account/confirmation(.:format)             devise/confirmations#show
             user_unlock POST   /account/unlock(.:format)                   devise/unlocks#create
         new_user_unlock GET    /account/unlock/new(.:format)               devise/unlocks#new
                         GET    /account/unlock(.:format)                   devise/unlocks#show
          calendar_posts GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)     posts#index
                         POST   /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)     posts#create
       new_calendar_post GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/new(.:format) posts#new
                         GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                         GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
               calendars GET    /calendars(.:format)                        calendars#index
                         POST   /calendars(.:format)                        calendars#create
            new_calendar GET    /calendars/new(.:format)                    calendars#new
           edit_calendar GET    /calendars/:id/edit(.:format)               calendars#edit
                calendar GET    /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#show
                         PATCH  /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#update
                         PUT    /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#update
                         DELETE /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#destroy
```

**UPDATE 3**: as per @Nathan's second comment, here is the content of my `show.html.erb` calendar view:

```
<h2><%= @calendar.name %> Calendar</h2>

<h3>Posts</h3>
<% if @calendar.posts.any? %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Format</th>
            <th>Copy</th>
            <th>Media</th>
        </tr>
  <% @calendar.posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= post.date %></td>
            <td><%= post.time %></td>
            <td><%= post.subject %></td>
            <td><%= post.format %></td>
            <td><%= post.copy %></td>
            <td><%= post.media %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Update', edit_post_path(@calendar, post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
<p>This calendar does not contain any post yet: just create one with the form below.</p>
<% end %>

<h3>Add a post to <%= @calendar.name %> Calendar:</h3>
<%= form_for([@calendar, @calendar.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :time %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :format %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :format %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :copy %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :copy %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :media %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :media %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_calendar_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', calendars_path %>
```

**UPDATE 4**: here are the routes when I remove the shallow option from the post resource:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /account/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /account/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /account/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /account/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /account/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /account/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /account/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /account/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /account(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /account/confirmation(.:format)             devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /account/confirmation/new(.:format)         devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /account/confirmation(.:format)             devise/confirmations#show
             user_unlock POST   /account/unlock(.:format)                   devise/unlocks#create
         new_user_unlock GET    /account/unlock/new(.:format)               devise/unlocks#new
                         GET    /account/unlock(.:format)                   devise/unlocks#show
          calendar_posts GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)     posts#index
                         POST   /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)     posts#create
       new_calendar_post GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/new(.:format) posts#new
                         GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                         GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
               calendars GET    /calendars(.:format)                        calendars#index
                         POST   /calendars(.:format)                        calendars#create
            new_calendar GET    /calendars/new(.:format)                    calendars#new
           edit_calendar GET    /calendars/:id/edit(.:format)               calendars#edit
                calendar GET    /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#show
                         PATCH  /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#update
                         PUT    /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#update
                         DELETE /calendars/:id(.:format)                    calendars#destroy
MacBook-Pro-de-Thibaud:calendy TXC$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                                                pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /account/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /account/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /account/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /account/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /account/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /account/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /account/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /account/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /account(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /account/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /account/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /account(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /account(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /account(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /account/confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /account/confirmation/new(.:format)              devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /account/confirmation(.:format)                  devise/confirmations#show
             user_unlock POST   /account/unlock(.:format)                        devise/unlocks#create
         new_user_unlock GET    /account/unlock/new(.:format)                    devise/unlocks#new
                         GET    /account/unlock(.:format)                        devise/unlocks#show
          calendar_posts GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                         POST   /calendars/:calendar_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
       new_calendar_post GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
      edit_calendar_post GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
           calendar_post GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                         PATCH  /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                         PUT    /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                         DELETE /calendars/:calendar_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
               calendars GET    /calendars(.:format)                             calendars#index
                         POST   /calendars(.:format)                             calendars#create
            new_calendar GET    /calendars/new(.:format)                         calendars#new
           edit_calendar GET    /calendars/:id/edit(.:format)                    calendars#edit
                calendar GET    /calendars/:id(.:format)                         calendars#show
                         PATCH  /calendars/:id(.:format)                         calendars#update
                         PUT    /calendars/:id(.:format)                         calendars#update
                         DELETE /calendars/:id(.:format)                         calendars#destroy
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What's your mark-up look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question with the content of the view files.

Comment: @ThibaudClement I think the relevant markup will be in your calendar view (assuming that's where you're clicking the "Edit" link before seeing this error).

Comment: Sure. I updated the question again.

Comment: Try removing the `shallow: true` and see what your routes look like.

Comment: Done, I have posted the new routes in the question, UPDATE 4.

Comment: Okay, so change your edit path now to: `edit_calendar_post_path(post)`

Comment: I forget if rails infers the calendar id, so if the above does not work, try `edit_calendar_post_path(@calendar, post)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two arguments are being passed in for a named path (`edit_post`) which expects one argument.  This is causing problems when the controller action `set_post` tries to determine which `:id` to use when looking up the record to set as `@post`.

It's also why you have that `.5` mysteriously appended to the end of your URL — I believe `5` is the `:id` of `post` (in that context), and `11` is the `:id` of `@calendar`.

`edit_post_path` only needs to know the `:id` of the post you want to edit, so you can fix this by changing `<%= link_to 'Update', edit_post_path(@calendar, post) %>` to `<%= link_to 'Update', edit_post_path(post) %>` *(note the removal of `@calendar`)*.

If you *really do* want to edit this post as a resource nested under calendar (at the path `/calendars/<calendar_id>/posts/<post_id>/edit`), take a look at your `config/routes.rb`.  The `shallow: true` option (which you used when nesting `:posts` under `:calendars`) is what's keeping the nested `:edit` path from being created.

You'll need to have that nested `:edit` path available, and then you can pass two arguments just as you are now (something like `edit_calendar_post_path(@calendar, post)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are correct: `<%= link_to 'Update', edit_post_path(post) %>` works like a charm. Thanks also for the rest of the explanation, that's very useful and highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this pass the calendar id?

Comment: @Nathan If he just removes the `@calendar` argument and keeps the same named path, then it will not include the calendar id.  If he makes the update I mentioned to the nested resource and passes in both arguments to `edit_calendar_post_path`, then it will include the calendar id.

Comment: Right, so what's confusing about that in his edit action he has: `@calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])` -- so not sure what his intensions are with that, but worth noting he will not be getting the calendar_id unless he uses the nested route or explicitly adding the params to the path.

Comment: @ThibaudClement: @Nathan makes a good point about what it *appears* you're trying to do in your `:edit` action.  Not having a `:calendar_id` available would be a problem if you do want/need `@calendar` to be available.

Answer (score 0):

The error makes me think there's a problem with the link you're building in your view template.  I'd help more but I do not see the View file or the output from `rake routes`.  Without those two things, its hard for me to tell you why your app is generating a funny url - but it usually means the view template is not calling the correct url_helper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated the question with the content of my view and the result of running `rake routes` in the Terminal. Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem his related to the `edit_post_path`. With shallow nesting, the edit route is outside of the parent scope. The `.5` is the Post ID being added to the url, but not as a valid url param because there's already an ID param from the calendar. Based on the way your routes are setup, it looks like you would need to set the id as a param in the link, like this:

```
link_to "edit post", edit_post_path(post)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do what you recommend, I get the following error: `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`. Any idea?

Comment: You don't have a @post instance variable, it should be just 'post'. Editing answer now. I believe edit_post_path(post) would work for you as well

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=11` error. Maybe I should avoid shallow routes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with shallow nesting. You must have something else in your view that is trying to query a Post with the Calendar id, but I don't see it... You removed the @calender from the link right?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the @calendar from the link.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why edit_post_path(post) would not work. Do you have anything else in your edit view besides the _form partial?